# Authenticating in ASP.NET MVC 5 with OWIN and Third-Party system without storing credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I want to authenticate a user using a third-party system when they hit a Controller or ApiController with the [Authorize] attribute, but I really don't want to have to create associated users and logins that OWIN requires in order to create the cookie that keeps the user session authorized, because our third-party system is already tracking that.

Normally, you'd map OWIN logins to external logins, but our system, as-is, is so tightly integrated with this third-party system that there are a bunch of reasons (that I won't go into) that we don't want to do that.

Is there a simple way to use ASP.NET MVC5 out of the box that allows you to authenticate to another system, and then mark the session as Authenticated without having to find/register them in OWIN?

Sorry if this isn't a lot to go on. I've not seen any way to go about this without perhaps implementing our own IAuthenticationManager, but I'm not even sure where I'd start to do that.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating my own implementation of IUserStore and its associated classes that wraps the third-party system.

Answer (score 1):

I believe OAuth is the only ASP.NET SSO support you get out of the box.  It would help if you elaborate on the nature of the third party authentication system, since you'll need to integrate with it in order to provide the SSO experience.

Here are a couple of blog posts explaining how to create custom OWIN authentication middleware, which seems to be what you'll need to do to set ASP.NET Identity based on some information from an external system (header, cookie, token, etc).  I used the second approach to integrate with CA SiteMinder (commercial web authentication product).

- [Owin Auth 1](http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-using-owin-middleware/)
- [Owin Auth 2](http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/owin-authentication-middleware-for-hawk-in-thinktecture-identitymodel-45/)